# Java: Using Constructor for JSlider

Tags: java, constructor

I am trying to build a panel in Java. The panel should have (among other things) a slider/JSlider.

Below is the class file for my JSlider. I would like to use the constructor to set the options for the slider.

I tried used a string hOrV (horizontal or vertical) to set the slider to JSlider.HORIZONTAL. This does not seem to work (the argument accepts an int, not a string).

In fact, no part of the constuctor seems to work when I call it in the other class.

None of the arguments seem to be passing to the constructor, can anyone help? Thanks ahead!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class ScrollBar extends JSlider
{

private JSlider slider;

public ScrollBar(String hOrV, int min, int max, int start)
{

//slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, min, max, start); //didn't work
slider = new JSlider(hOrV, min, max, start);

add(slider);

}


//This is the call in my other class file
slider = new ScrollBar("JSlider.HORIZONTAL", 0, 50, 10);

//I have also tried:
slider = new ScrollBar(0, 50, 10); // with public ScrollBar(int min, int max, int start) as my constructor
slider = new ScrollBar(0, 0, 50, 10); //with public ScrollBar(int hOrV, int min, int max, int start) as my constructor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the parameters to `JSlider`'s constructor, according to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSlider.html#JSlider%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29): `int orientation, int min, int max, int value`.

The orientations can be `SwingConstants.VERTICAL` or `SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL`. Note that these are integers, not strings.

You have multiple options:

1) You could make your constructor like this:

```
public ScrollBar(String hOrV, int min, int max, int start)
{
    slider = new JSlider(hOrV.equals("HORIZONTAL") ?
            SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL : SwingConstants.VERTICAL,
        min, mas, start);
}
```

And then you could call it like this:

```
new ScrollBar("HORIZONTAL", 0, 50, 10); // or "VERTICAL"
```

2) Alternatively, you could simply have an `int` passed to your constructor, and expect the constructing code to access `SwingConstants` for the right integer:

```
public ScrollBar(int hOrV, int min, int max, int start)
{
    slider = new JSlider(hOrV, min, mas, start);
}
```

Call like this:

```
new ScrollBar(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, 0, 50, 10); // or SwingConstants.VERTICAL
```

3) Or you could make your own pair of values for horizontal/vertical:

```
public final int HORIZONTAL = SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL;
public final int VERTICAL = SwingConstants.VERTICAL;
public ScrollBar(int hOrV, int min, int max, int start)
{
    slider = new JSlider(hOrV, min, mas, start);
}
```

Call like this:

```
new Slider(Slider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 50, 10); // or Slider.VERTICAL
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answer!

Comment: @Greg If this answer works for you, then consider upvoting and marking it as correct so that future visitors to this question know that it is correct.

Comment: @Jashazun I marked it correct - thanks again! I'm new here so my upvote isn't visible but you can bet that I am very grateful for your response!

Comment: @Greg I'm happy to help.